# Custom dialog (derived from QDialog) would not close (Android)

Tags: android, c++, qt

Alright there's a custom QDialog (class derived from QDialog) , stuff populated from QML, it works it opens just fine it behaves as desired, but then when we want to kill it using

```
mDialog-> close() or mDialog->hide()
```

all the animations within the dialog halt, everything within it freezes but.. it doesn't close.

if you wonder how we initiate the destruction process, there's a button within the QML which sends a signal to the C++ back-end, the back-end holds pointer to the dialog and tries to close.
 The dialog is opened with showFullScreen so ther's nothing blocking (exec would block)
Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After many human-work-hours, we stumbled upon a FIX.

Lo and behold. So for this to work we had to

```
dialog->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose,true);
```

before trying to close().

Now there's nothing in documentation suggesting that something like this would be required? Supposedly a BUG, right?

conversely for instance a sequence of:

```
 dialog->close() /// hide()/ reject()
delete dialog;
```

would result in an exception with QT saying something about its processing queue being pre-occupied and us trying to kill it.